# How do I say car is tilting/leaning in one direction in parking spot?

Tags: word-usage, phrases

Often parking spots have straight lines between which you have to park your car, parallel to the line. However, let's say, I see a car a parked diagonally between the two lines.

> How would I describe the car alignment wrt the parking spot?

Should I used the word lean/tilt? 
And say I want to tell someone to correct the alignment, should I say

> Park your car straight?

This is the literal translation of the expression I would have used in my native language, I would like to know if this is how native speakers would say it?

Comment: No, "lean" or "tilt" is more about a difference with a plumb line.  You can use "askew", "diagonally", "misaligned", "not parallel"...

Comment: *This* native speaker thinks ***askew*** is somewhat dated/poetic (like ***afoot, afar, a-roaming***, but not like ***asleep, aloud***). But I'd quite happily say *Your car in parked **on the skew.** Please park more carefully next time.*

Comment: If they're parked diagonally between the lines, that's *crooked*.  But if they go over the line, and particularly if they're over it by a significant amount, that's known as *double-parking*, and the world would be a better place if [this](https://xkcd.com/562/) was considered an acceptable response.

Comment: @FumbleFingers where are you from? That is totally unnatural to me.

Comment: @PressTilty: I'm UK South East, as it says [in my profile](http://ell.stackexchange.com/users/126/fumblefingers?tab=profile). I suppose if you think *parked on the skew* is "unnatural", you'll probably think [*parked skew-whiff*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22parked+skew-whiff%22) is even more weird. They're both pretty ordinary colloquialisms to me, but my main point was that the dated prefix version ***askew*** isn't a word I'd often use.

Comment: Yup that's pretty weird. I was just curious, since I had never heard it before

Answer (score 27, accepted):

"Lean" or "tilt" would give the impression that the car was in danger of tipping over. The most common way to describe it where I am from (northeast US) is ***crooked***. Some examples:

> That car is too crooked for another car to fit next to it.

or

> That car is parked crookedly.

To get someone to correct a parking attempt, you would tell them to

> Straighten up your car!

Comment: +1 for _crooked_ in the northwest corner of the U.S. too!

Comment: note that it's pronounced "crook-ed" where the "ed" is like the name "Ed" or the last half of "head". - Word looked weird to me at first because I'm more used to hearing it than seeing it.

Comment: English is such a beautiful language with all its exceptions ;-) @DoubleDouble

Comment: @StephanBijzitter As I learned in school "I before E, except after C, except when it isn't"

Comment: @corsiKa The rule I learned was "I before E, except after C, and except in A, as in neighbor or weigh". Basically you can use the rule except when the "ei" syllable has a long A sound. Stupid rule/grammatical exception, but it works in most cases (I haven't been interested enough to expound to see if it's truly universal.)

Comment: @TimS. "weird" is a weird case. kaleidescope, too.

Comment: I would have guessed it wasn't universal. Just another saying with two more (of the probably hundreds) of exceptions.. nice.

Answer (score 9):

In my experience, most native speakers would use the term ***diagonal*** when referring to misalignment and ***line up*** or ***straighten*** when giving a direction to do the same.

Example

> Your car is parked slightly ***diagonally***. Please ***straighten*** it.

Answer (score 9):

As you ask for common phrases, without implying formality, here are some examples that are common in the UK:

- to be parked *on the skew*,
- to be parked *skew-whiff* (pronounced skewiff),
- to be parked *at an angle*,
- to be parked **wonky** (credit to @AndyT)
- **(caution: vulgar, but not uncommon)** to be parked *on the piss*.

If in doubt, *at an angle* is probably more universally understood in the UK. *Skew-whiff* is the most common in my experience region (Mid West). The latter example is generally seen as more critical (It isn't something you would generally tell your grandma) and should be avoided if you do not which to cause offense - however, I have kept it in the list in case you hear it in conversation: it is not to be taken literally.

This brings me to a cultural point. In the UK, at least, it is more common to describe the parking with comparison to that of more considerate drivers. Put simply, the most common description of the situation would be "the car is parked *badly*".

Comment: As an ex-pat Brit, these are definitely the phrases I'd use.

Comment: "on the piss" would definitely be valid, and I do understand it to mean "at an angle", i.e. it is a description of the position, not of the driver.

Comment: Another phrase I'd use in the UK is "wonky", as in "he's parked his car a bit wonky". (I didn't think this was worth making an answer on its own. Feel free to edit it into yours if you like it).

Comment: Thanks! Im glad I'm not the only one here who has heard/used that phrasing. I've only really heard it used when being critical of the action (i.e. *it was* parked *on the piss*, *you've* fitted the light switch *on the piss*), so I've updated for clarity (assuming this is a correct depiction) and added your suggestion with credit @AndyT.

Answer (score 5):

A car that is not parked correctly relative to the lines is [askew](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/askew?s=t)

Comment: No, it's not. I mean, you could say that and not be incorrect, but *no one would ever say this* except in the most technical of contexts. The car is parked diagonally or not straight or crooked, but no one would ever say that it's *askew*.

Comment: @sgroves While crooked might be more common, askew is definitely not unheard of.

Comment: @sgroves google's ngram tool backs me up, https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=parked+crooked%2C+parked+askew&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cparked%20crooked%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cparked%20askew%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I would certainly use this...

Comment: It was the first word that came to mind for me as well, but I agree that "crooked" would be considered more common/informal in the US.

Answer (score 4):

I'm from the Southwest US and live in California now, and some of the other answers, like "crookedly", "askew" or "on the skew" sound weird to me. "Diagonally", to me, implies that it's parked at a 45 degree angle to take up two spots on purpose. I would say that "the car is angled", "parked on (or over) the line", and "needs to be straightened".

Answer (score 4):

Though there are more precise words for it, I would actually use the phrase "not straight"

> That car is not parked straight.
>   The car is not straight. (*"parked" is implied*)
>   See how the car isn't [parked] straight?

Then your literal translation to correct the straightness is pretty close.

> Try to park more straightly next time.
>   Will you straighten out the car for me?
>   Try to straighten the car.
>   Please straighten out the car.

Comment: Try to park *more straightly* next time.

Comment: In casual, spoken American English we tend to adverbize things on a whim. "Try to park straight next time" sounds much more natural. I wouldn't write it in a textbook, but I'd certainly say it that way.

Answer (score 2):

No-one seems to have mentioned the word "**slant**" yet.  You could describe the car as "parked on the slant" (this might be a Britishism, although the word "slant" is not) or "slanting".

Comment: The "Britishism" is just from the structure of "on the" - U.S. would say: "the car is parked slanted"

Answer (score 1):

Another colloquialism, but "your parking is shit" should cover any form of positional errors.

Also "you park like a nanna" also implies a poor job of parking, but does not suggest the effort was substandard, just the end result.

Answer (score 1):

To me, a native New Yorker living in California, the most easily understood phrase would be "That was a crooked job of parking." You can't say,"You parked crooked." Because you need to use an adverb, "You parked crookedly." And I would say that was a questionable word to use, that is, not frequently heard.

Answer (score 1):

A British expression, that I've never heard from elsewhere is simply to say the parking is [*Wonky*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=40&safe=active&site=&source=hp&q=define+wonky&oq=define+wonky&gs_l=hp.3..0l2j0i22i30l2.951.2613.0.4057.13.11.0.0.0.0.354.1573.0j2j2j2.6.0....0...1.1.64.hp..8.5.1443.0.dnkPvwBdjeA).

Wonky can be applied to anything that isn't straight or isn't functioning correctly.

Comment: I've begun to use "wonky" on a regular basis. American peers find it weird, but the meaning is obvious.